# Log into OSX via the command line

Tags: macos, bash, authentication, unix

I want to be able to authenticate with the [login window](http://4sysops.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Network-accounts-are-unavailable-error-in-Mac-OS-X-Lion_thumb.png) via the command line. I don't know if this is even possible, but if it is, I'd really like to know how it's done.

I've worked out the process is called "loginwindow" but I can't work out how to to pass it any parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: That was bizarre. I would guess you can't, but who knows? Should be interesting to find out.

Comment: It would probably help if you added some more context about what you are *really* trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to be able to log into a Mac running OSX Lion via the command line/ARD so that I don't have to walk around a room, typing in the username and password required to log into the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
#!bin/sh
cat >/tmp/Login_Automatically.sh <<-"EOF"
if [[ "$(who | grep console)" == "" ]]; then # Runs ONLY if no one is logged in
osascript <<EOT
set username_ to "username"
set password_ to "password"
tell application "System Events"
```

(via http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2010021119293586)

Also, can't you disable the authentication all together in the system preferences if you want a way to bypass the login?

Or if you want to kill it read:
[Kill "loginwindow" process using command line in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620606/kill-loginwindow-process-using-command-line-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Nine times out of ten, users login with their own username's and password's but sometimes, I want to authenticate with a local account.
I've tried the command but I get this error: "377:438: execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get text field 1 of group 1 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent". Invalid index. (-1719)". Am I doing something silly?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the comments of [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2010021119293586).

Copy and paste into Command Line/ARD:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "usernamegoeshere"'; \
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab'; \
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "passwordgoeshere"'; \
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke return'
```

Thanks to Sam Mirrado for providing the link to the article.

[Source](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2010021119293586). Comment by engelby on Feb 16, '10 02:09:32PM.